# How to get Facebook group member count in html document?

Tags: facebook

I want to get the total number of members count of my fb group in a HTML document tag (div) which I admin. Need the complete code where I can replace only the ID and APT secret.

Comment: The Page Plugin doesn't support groups...

Comment: if you want "complete code", hire a developer. stackoverflow is a platform where people help other developers solving their specific problems, not where people do your work for free.

Comment: I'm not asking to develop or work for me for FREE ! I asked for complete code if some one already have. Most of time people share just the query like FQL n we need to again search for rest of the code. So I preferred to have complete code where we can only replace the API secret n FB ID n Thanks for ur Answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible because the Group object in the Graph API doesn't have a members count field. You could iterate through the members list though...

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/members/

Comment: fixed a typo for you. *fistbump*